# DecimalFormat, how to set maximum number of integer digits via patern?

Tags: java, formatting, numbers

I want to format a number using DecimalFormat.
The maximum number of integer (and fractional) digits must be 2.
If the number is 345561.7301 the desired result would be: 61.73

This is my code:

```
double number = 345561.7301;
DecimalFormat formater =              
    (DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);//This locale only    

formater.applyPattern("00.00");

System.out.println(formater.format(number));
```

I do not want to use setMaximumIntegerDigits() method.

Comment: So what about your current solution doesn't work?

Comment: I get 345561.73, but I want: 61.73

Comment: Looks like `formatter.setMaximumIntegerDigits(2);` is the simplest you can get to achieve what you want. Any reason why don't want to use that?

Comment: well, the reason would be that the pattern will be passed by string. If I could use this pattern directly this would be grate otherwise it will require me to pass special string like: "1,2,1,2" (minimum integer, maximum integer, minimum fractional,..) , split the string into integer array (with casting)  and apply values in appropriate methods => time consuming operation if I have a lot of values that i want to format.

Answer (score 3):

What about just using substring?

```
double number = 345561.7301;
DecimalFormat formater =              
(DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);  //This locale only    
formater.applyPattern("00.00");
//formater.setMaximumIntegerDigits(2); // <- don't want to use this
String tmp = formater.format(number);
System.out.println(tmp.substring(tmp.length() - 5));
```

Comment: I am curious why you don't want to use setMaximumIntegerDigits.

Comment: please see my comment above that answers you question.

Comment: I'd make the magic number 5 the length of the applyPattern.  Good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pattern might not be the best option in this scenario.  I would reccommend using modulus division '%' and get the remainder of number/100.

```
double number = 345561.7301 % 100;
DecimalFormat formater = (DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
formater.applyPattern("00.00");

System.out.println(formater.format(number));
```

Comment: I know I can do various business logics, but I wanted to know if this can be done via pattern only.

Comment: You are trying to force the pattern to do something it wasn't intended to do.